# WCF Service With Restricted/Special Characters in Response

Tags: wcf, xmlserializer

I have a WCF Service which returns a string response with &, <, >. For e.g.

```
<response>&amp;</response>
```

Actually, I'm sending the '&' char but it is encoded for some reason.

Instead, I would like to send the decoded resoponse. The response I want is - `<response>&</response>`

Could someone suggest how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML Serializer has to encode special characters in order to generate a well-formed XML document.

According to the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#syntax), the ampersand character **must not** appear in its literal form anywhere in the document, hence the encoding.

The consuming application should be aware of this already, and will know to decode the &amp ; back to ampersand. However, if you are looking at your response on a XML-based software such as Soap UI, you'll continue to see the symbol in its encoded form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

on your perticular data contract property/entire response string. Or you can use method in below article that is not quite developer freindly but may be used if you have lots of special chars in your response.

http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/11/09/xml-web-services-and-special-characters/

Comment: Thanks Ajay. But System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() works only at the client side if I use it just before displaying the response. It doesn't help if I add in the DataMember property. get { return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(response); }
            set { response = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value); }

Comment: Actually what happens is, I'm not assigning encoded string to the response. WCF service encodes it while sending response, I think.

Comment: You have to do in on client side itself. I know youreself not encoding WCF does this on its own. DataMember property the way you did will not work. what is the problem doing on client side ?

Comment: We are sending a courier tracking information (URL) in this resposne. So I have to ask our customers (mention about decoding in the spec) to decode our response on their consuming application. Just thought we don't have to mention this to our customers/doc if we can send the decoded string from our WCF Service itself.